# Overriding a label in Zend Fom config XML

Tags: zend-framework

Hi I am using an xml file of the following structure:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <configdata>
    <page>    
                 <form action="" method="post">
            <elements>
                <page_title type="text" name="page_title" >
                    <options label="Page Title" required="true" />
                </page_title>

                <page_content type="textarea" name="page_content">
                    <options label="Page Content" />
                </page_content>

            </elements> 
            </form>
           </page>
```

I have two forms which take exactly the same data, but I need to change the labels on the form. I would rather not just cut and paste the code contained within `<page></page>` and adjust the labels. Is there a way I can 'extend' page and set the labels that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to do it right from the controller (i know it works with normal Zend_form objects)

```
$form = new Your_Form_Here();
$form->Elementname->setLabel('new label');
```

That's all there is to it. You may have to make some adjustments because you're using a config file but it should'nt be to hard.